# jQuery navigate only visible items after filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have made a simple arrow key navigation list (using firedevs jquery keynav plugin) which can be seen here:
https://output.jsbin.com/zowowo

To edit:
https://jsbin.com/zowowo/edit?html,css,js

It works right now but after clicking on Contact Group 1 or 2 menu to filter the list with .toggle(), it's still navigating the removed/hidden list items. Tried also using .remove() instead, but the same problem remains. The only way I could get it to work was to make a complete refresh of the page with different html.

I would like to simply be able to navigate only the shown items after filtering and the removed ones should not be navigable. One idea is to make it hidden instead of removing and in the script check if it's visible, otherwise ignore it but I'm not sure how to accomplish that since I'm new to frontend. There are probably various ways to accomplish the result.

I would really appreciate if some frontend pro can shed some light, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, was this thing problematic.

So, first I created a method within the function called eupdate(short for external update).

Then I edited  your click events to include some checks to see if the current selection was visible after click, and if not, make the first visible element your current.
I had to add a reset current within the method.

Please have a look at the output found here:

https://output.jsbin.com/zegirid

Editable version here:

https://jsbin.com/zegirid/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

I added some notations to show what I did.

Comment: I just looked at your solution and it's amazing! I learned something new.. Thanks a lot for this and for your time, it means a lot!

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the challenge.